# Where do I ask a question about how the elements within pressurised cans react?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I had a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124255/do-pressurised-cans-still-pose-a-risk-to-bursting-in-normal-conditions-but-afte) about how elements within pressurised cans react under certain conditions, I wasn't 100% sure, but I thought [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) may have been the correct place, but it seems not as it was put on hold stating that:

> This question does not appear to be about chemistry within the scope defined in the help center.

I thought Chemistry was the correct place as it's more about how the elements react rather than the container they are being held within, but I guess I am wrong!?

If Chemistry is not the correct place, where do I ask a question such as this?

Comment: From the offset I was thinking Chemistry, but when I read your question it seems like it might be more suited to [the Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @KyleFairns Thanks. Perhaps it is, just updated my question a little to indicate why I thought Chemistry was more suitable than something like Engineering as my question was more about the elements than the structure holding them.

Comment: Reading the question it indeed sounds more like an engineering one as you ask about the safety of your pressure vessels and their behaviour when (having been) exposed to environments beyond their specification (higher temperature). The contents of the pressure vessel is of little interest for this (unless you are asking how the contents change when exposed to heat - but you don't seem to). I'd try engineering, and maybe physics

Comment: Would Physics take this?

Comment: @planetmaker Oh ok, makes sense. I thought it would the elements inside that reacted to the heat and "made" the container burst rather than the container itself.

Comment: @Brett the gas inside reacts by building up the pressure as it heats. That's simple physics. But the chemistry of the gas usually is irrelevant, unless it's corrosive, explosive or something in the line of chemical reactions going on when heating. The reaction of the container to the pressure, that's either engineering or physics (or both).